# How can I limit the output of Get-ChildItem to one line

Tags: powershell

The command to shows me the thumbprint of my certificate:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\MY | Where-Object {$_.Subject -Match "MYCERT"} | Select-Object Thumbprint

1.Thumbprint
2.----------
3.6DFD904457E6AFA01E406FD6FC2B34DB4B829672
```

I would like to output only line 3, how can I filter the output here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-ExpandProperty` [parameter to expand the *`Thumbprint`*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#parameters) property.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\MY | 
            Where-Object {$_.Subject -Match "MYCERT"} | 
            Select-Object Thumbprint -ExpandProperty "Thumbprint"
```